# Why are shared libraries on Linux executable?

Tags: linux

I'm just curious.

```
bash-3.00$  ldd libmylibrary.so
ldd: warning: you do not have execution permission for `libmylibrary.so'
```

Everything seems to work fine just with +r. I noticed that most of the .so's in /usr/lib do have +x set...

Why are shared libs supposed to have executable bit set? What could happen if I don't set it?

Comment: Libraries definitely don't need +x to run properly. Perhaps they're links however? Links would need +x to be followed.

Comment: Yes, they don't need +x, yet most of the libraries has it set.

Comment: This question has also been asked on Unix&Linux: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40587/why-are-shared-libraries-executable (and got the correct answer there)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually it depends on the `ldd` implementation. `ldd` is usually a script, you can edit it to see where and why you get that error.

On Ubuntu 10.04, `ldd` checks for the `read` permission only. It may give the error *not a dynamic executable* if the file is not a ELF (*Executable and Linkable Format*). The libs here are all `-rw-r--r--`, for instance

```
$ find /usr/lib -type f -name "libm*.so*" -ls
(...)
-rw-r--r--   1 root     root       216800 Feb 26 22:20 /usr/lib/libmp.so.3.1.16
-rw-r--r--   1 root     root        76728 Mar 14 04:23 /usr/lib/libmjpegutils-1.9.so.0.0.0
-rw-r--r--   1 root     root       134464 Jan 29  2010 /usr/lib/libm17n-core.so.0.3.0
-rw-r--r--   1 root     root       290480 Feb 17  2010 /usr/lib/libmtp.so.8.3.2
```

It isn't shocking to want an `x` access for a shared library. The `executable` mode is a convention that gives the OS another level of access rights control. The executable loader controls that access, to ensure the user can execute it, but also to prevent errors (some scripts or programs should not be executed by some people).

This could be extended to the shared libraries for the same reason - but shared libraries cannot *run* by themselves, and are less error prone to be used *by accident*). Thus the need is less obvious (the `r` access suffices).

Comment: Note also that this warning is just a warning, it doesn't prevent further processing.

Answer (score 4):

You can actually execute a lot of libraries, see for example what happens when you type `/lib/libc.so.6` at your shell on a recent GNU/Linux system.

Answer (score -1):

think like having an executable file with -x. You won't be able to execute it.
Consider these libraries as a collection of general functions, that are being called by another program (let's say myProgra). If you cannot execute the libraries / function ... then you have nothing

An example

```
function1() {} 
function2() {} 
int main() { 
printf("Let's call func1"); 
function1(); 
printf("Let's call func2"); 
function2(); 
}
```

Now if you place function1 and function2 in another file and you include it, then you a library. (Of course it's something more complicated. This is just an example)

But in any case, as you can see, you have to execute the code that is being included in the library

Comment: But you execute executables, not libraries.

Comment: See the edited version above

Answer (score -1):

The key is the file format, Executable and Linkable Format.  Since the same exact file format is used to identify both an executable and a shared library, both must have the appropriate executable permissions for the OS loader.  This allows for a single loader and for executables to be used as a DSO if they include a symbol table.

Comment: So, the loader uses permission bits, not the file header, to identify things to load?

Comment: The loader uses the file header to identify the contents as DYN or EXEC and do the appropriate thing.  The execute bit is for the OS, not the loader.  ELF is an executable format, without the execute bit, the OS won't allow the loader to execute the file in order to read the headers.  Check out wikipedia for more on ELF http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format.